# How to I pass a table from Lua into C++?

Tags: c++, api, lua, lua-table

How would I pass a table of unknown length from Lua into a bound C++ function?

I want to be able to call the Lua function like this:

```
call_C_Func({1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21})
```

And copy the table contents into an array (preferably STL vector)?

Comment: Are you just using the raw Lua c-api? Or are you using one of the many libraries ToLua, lua++, luabind? The details of the answer will depend on your approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [LuaBind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) it's as simple as one registered call. As for rolling up your own, you need to take a look at [lua_next](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_next) function.

Basically the code is as follows:

```
lua_pushnil(state); // first key
index = lua_gettop(state);
while ( lua_next(state,index) ) { // traverse keys
  something = lua_tosomething(state,-1); // tonumber for example
  results.push_back(something);
  lua_pop(state,1); // stack restore
}
```

Comment: Is the usage of lua_next() correct? For the next() function the Lua manual states "The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices."

If this is true for lua_next() as well you might not get the values in the expected order.

Answer (score 3):

This would be my attempt (without error checking):

```
int lua_test( lua_State *L ) {
    std::vector< int > v;
    const int len = lua_objlen( L, -1 );
    for ( int i = 1; i <= len; ++i ) {
        lua_pushinteger( L, i );
        lua_gettable( L, -2 );
        v.push_back( lua_tointeger( L, -1 ) );
        lua_pop( L, 1 );
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
        std::cout << v[ i ] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use lua_objlen:

> Returns the "length" of the
>   value at the given acceptable index:
>   for strings, this is the string
>   length; for tables, this is the result
>   of the length operator ('#'); for
>   userdata, this is the size of the
>   block of memory allocated for the
>   userdata; for other values, it is 0.

Comment: Q: How do I pass a table from lua into C++? A: Use `lua_objlen`.